# Programatically create Visio drawing on a linux server

Tags: visio

Is it possible to create Visio drawings from a Linux server ?

That is, without access to the Visio software. Language can be python, php, C ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: Yes

There are a couple of options available to you:

1 - Generate VDX or VSDX files. These are XML-based formats that Visio can read. (VSDX is new and can only be read by Visio 2013). If you can generate XML files on Linux then you can create these files. I wrote such a library that can help create VDX files - Look for VisioAutomation.VDX here: https://github.com/saveenr/VisioAutomation
also you could look at http://pkgvisio.codeplex.com/.

2 - Generate VSD. This is a binary format and harder to create. LibreOffice has a library to generate this format. Also the "Aspose.Diagram" can do this but as-far-as-I-know does not work on a Linux server.

Comment: You wrote "VDX" for both options, a mistake I guess ? Also do you know of any lib that allows to create such an XML file ?

Comment: I meant VSD for option #2. I've corrected the mistake and added links to some code that can create VDX and VSDX files in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you, i'll look at the examples you posted. I mark your answer as valid even if I didn't use it yet, because after a lot of Googling those are the only options available at that time.