# Generate *.vsd or *.vdx file using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, visio

I'm using Python 2.7, Ubuntu 15.  I have a database with some data with which I need to create a graph.  This graph can be very large, and I am not able to print it in Firefox (as the client-side has already been done), so I want to export the graph to PDF or Visio.  The PDF format is good, but the standard Ubuntu printing program doesn't have "Poster Print", like in Adobe Reader and I can't install anything else.  Ubuntu does however have Libre Office which can open *.vsd's.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100664/programatically-create-visio-drawing-on-a-linux-server) information, but it is not enough for me.  I need more information, please tell me how I can create VSD files in Python, examples, docs, python libraries or some other information.

I have created test.vdx file and write code there ([I took it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa218409%28v=office.10%29.aspx)):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<VisioDocument xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:visio">
  <Pages>
    <Page ID="0" NameU="Page-1">
      <Shapes>
        <Shape ID="3" Type="Shape" LineStyle="1" FillStyle="1" TextStyle="3">
          <XForm>
            <PinX>3</PinX>
            <PinY>9</PinY>
          </XForm>
          <Text>
            <cp IX="0"/>
            Hello World!
          </Text>
        </Shape>
      </Shapes>
    </Page>    
  </Pages>
</VisioDocument>
```

Libreoffice doesn't open it. But it's open [other example](http://www.visguy.com/2006/11/30/visio-and-xml-conference-resources/). I can't find the reason.

Comment: So you need to convert database data into a graph and the graph needs to be in visio format?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes, I need create graph in visio format. It is not XY problem I can't find right library (*.VSD) or xml format documentation (*.VDX, * .VSDX).

Comment: I have found that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa218409(v=office.10).aspx, do you know something better?

Comment: Pretty sure Ubuntu would be able to print a PDF whatever size you wish. See [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Size is able, BUT I need another. I have printer, the paper for printer is A4. But I have to print A3, so I need to split A3 on two A4. Adobe Reader support it (poster print) and standart Ubuntu printing doesn't support (I can't install anything).